# create a persistant instance of aiohttp.ClientSession in Django app

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to create an instance of aiohttp.ClientSession() in a django app. I want to create the object via the ready() hook in apps.py and then access the instance from views.py.

From views.py I'm using the my_app_config.my_object to pull back the instance, but I'm seeing weird behaviour.  For example 'Timeout context manager should be used in side a task'.

Is anyone able to provide a clear example of how I might go about creating an instance of aiohttp.ClientSession() which I can pull into views.py (or indeed any other class in the app) for reuse.